# JSON Date Serialization and Time Zones

Tags: .net, json, datetime, timezone, json.net

I'm having issues displaying the correct date on the client's browser using a JSON serialized object.  The user is able to define what time zone they want to view data as.  Given this, I convert the UTC date to the user's time zone on the server.  Then I want to serialize the date/times (which are already converted to their defined time zone) to the browser via JSON.

Seems simple, however the JSON serializers I've been using have been severely mucking up my dates.  The server is in UTC and the client is in Central (-6).  The dates are being ajusted (-12 hours) even though I am specifying the DateTime.Kind to Unspecified.

Somehow .NET knows what time zone the client's browser is at and what time zone the server is in and it is negating -6 from my dates/times even though I've already ajusted the time per the user's global settings and set the dates' kind to be unspecified.  How can I get the JSON serializers to NOT try and adjust my dates?

```
List<ErrorGridModel> models = Mapper.Map<ErrorCollection, List<ErrorGridModel>>(errors);
foreach (ErrorGridModel m in models)
{
    //convert UTC dates to user local dateTime - split out date vs. time for grouping & splitting columns
    DateTime dtLocal = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(m.ErrorDate, this.AppContext.User.TimeZoneInfo);
    m.ErrorDate = new DateTime(dtLocal.Year, dtLocal.Month, dtLocal.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    m.ErrorTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, dtLocal.Hour, dtLocal.Minute, dtLocal.Second, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
}
IQueryable<ErrorGridModel> dataSource = models.AsQueryable();
return new ContentResult() { Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSource.ToDataSourceResult(request), new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat }), ContentType = "application/json" };
//return Json(dataSource.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

ISO dates appear to work, but I can't use them as I have 3rd party controls that want the older Microsoft format... which adjusts the time zones on me.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your problem, but if you want to push the date logic to javascript - check out moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a long discussion on the exact situation that I have been in.  http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/grids-and-dates.aspx

Bottom line, if you are using the Microsoft JSON date format, it will always reflect the date in UTC as the number of milliseconds (ticks) from 1/1/1970 UTC.  There's no way for me to auto-convert the time to local on the server and send what it should be down via JSON to the Kendo Grid as the Kendo Grid control instantiates the date from the ticks in JS as UTC.  When displaying this date, it will auto-convert the value to the browser's local time zone.

The only way to show my server's converted date value from the server is to send the date via JSON as a string to the client.

Comment: your kendo link is broken, do you have good link... having same issue here.

Answer (score 4):

When you're trying to control offsets, don't rely on `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  It has a few quirks that are often interpreted as `Unspecified == Local`.  The only way to get Json.Net to specifically encode the correct offset (regardless of ISO or MS format) is to pass it a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`.

```
// Start with the UTC time, for example your m.ErrorDate.
// Here I demonstrate with UtcNow.  Any DateTime with .Kind = UTC is ok.
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;

// Use the appropriate time zone, here I demonstrate with EST.
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

// Get the offset from UTC for the time zone and date in question.
var offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(dt);

// Get a DateTimeOffset for the date, and adjust it to the offset found above.
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToOffset(offset);

// Serialize to json
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    });


// The json should now contain the correct time and offset information.
// For example,  "\/Date(1358789156229-0500)\/"
```

Now hopefully you will find that the javascript controls you are using will honor the offset and apply it appropriately.  If not, then the rest of the problem is specific to the control you are using.

Comment: Well, I tried your idea.  +1 for a good idea.  Unfortunately the Kendo Grid (3rd-party control) that I am using is not working with offset information :(  My last idea is to possibly create my own Date converter and pass it to JSON.NET.  Then my dates which are converted server-side to the user's desired timezone will be passed via JSON without .NET auto-adjusting the times on me.

Comment: @BillChristenson You should read [this article](http://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/kendoui-tips-and-tricks-on-dates-in-a-grid/).  The author describes how to deal with dates in kendo grids.  He also shows how you can accept ISO formatted date input [here](http://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/kendoui-supporting-iso-8601-dates/), which would be much better IMHO than using the microsoft date format.

Comment: Yes, I've read those blogs.  I'm using the AJAX/JSON MVC server wrappers which is a different implementation than he's using.  I also don't want to tweak their .js files if I can get away with it.  I'll let you guys know how my custom JSON.NET converter works.  I'm getting close to finishing it.

Comment: Pass as an ISO string after converting it to the proper DateTimeOffset like I showed.  Then on the client, use a library like MomentJS to parse the string to a Javascript date without the local offset getting in the way.  Then bind that date to your control.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem as well. As you note, the problem is actually happening on the client side. By using a request end handler in your grid, you can convert the date back to UTC. Example found here:

http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides.aspx